# Do enabling flashback slows down updates/inserts in oracle?

Tags: oracle, flashback

I have two doubts around oracle flashback queries:

1. Is the flashback feature enabled by default in Oracle?  Because in a few of my tables I see null values in versions_startscn and others version columns.
2. Does flashback slows down inserts/updates in Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

- Q1: Flashback query is enable by default (it uses information in Undo
  Tablespace).
- Q2: By default, management Undo Tablespace is a mandatory activity
  of Oracle in order to run normally. Flashback query just uses
  available information in Undo Tablespace, it doesn't force database
  have to execute something special in order to support it working
  properly. So I do not think flashback query will impact on DBMS
  performance.